# I'm trying to add my total together from a table, and have no idea how to go about it

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to add my total together from this code, and dont know how to go about it.
here is the script i've been working on, where their money earned doubles everyday.

```
<script>
    // asks for the days you worked
    var daysworked = parseFloat(prompt("daysworked", "100"));
//equation and table for the days worked
    for (var days = 1; days <= daysworked; days++) {
        document.write("<tr><td>"+ days +"</td>");

        // here is specifically the equation and how i output it 
        document.write("<td>" + "$" + ( Math.pow(2 , days - 1)*0.01) +"</td></tr>");
```

How should i add up the total amount of money made?

Comment: How much does the person make per day? And why are you having it double every day?

Comment: on the first day he makes .01, and each day his payday doubles, so day two, he would make .02. i was wondering how i should add up all the days money together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will give you a hint:

```
var earningsPerDay = 77;
var totalEarnings = 0;

for (var days = 1; days <= daysworked; days++) {
    totalEarnings = totalEarnings + earningsPerDay;

    document.write("<tr><td>"+ days +"</td>");

    document.write("<td>" + "$" + totalEarnings +"</td></tr>");
}
```

**UPDATE**

After your explanation, here is a better answer:

```
var totalEarnings = 0;

for (var days = 1; days <= daysworked; days++) {
    todaysEarnings = Math.pow(2 , days - 1) * 0.01;
    totalEarnings = totalEarnings + todaysEarnings;

    document.write("<tr><td>"+ days +"</td>");

    document.write("<td>" + "$" + todaysEarnings +"</td></tr>");
}
document.write("<tr><td>" + "Total: $" + totalEarnings +"</td></tr>");
```

or:

```
document.write("<td>" + "$" + todaysEarnings +"</td><td>" + totalEarnings + "</td></tr>");
```

Comment: thank you, this helps alot!